# Can the keychain be used like a NSUserDefaults on steroids for storing NSData?

Tags: ios, cocoa, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

Can [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html) be used like a `NSUserDefaults` on steroids? I mean, for example, to store `NSData` used in a game?

My intent is to store a `NSData` element that will be essentially the representation of an array or dictionaries.

So the questions are:

Suppose I create a wrapper using Apple's `KeychainItemWrapper` class. Is this `kSecValueData` mentioned on the keychain documentation referring to a `NSData` object?

If so I can do this, right?

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArrayOfDicts];
KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"myID" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:myData forKey:kSecValueData];
```

Second question: if this is the case, is there a limit on the `NSData` size that can be stored on keychain item?

Comment: I assume you want to persist your data between deletion/reinstall of your app? That's where the keychain is different form user defaults, AFAIK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is any limit and you definitely can store NSData, however performance will not be very good. Quoting Apple's documentation:

> The keychain is intended for storing small amounts of sensitive data that are specific to your app. It is not intended as a general-purpose mechanism for encrypting and storing data.

I wouldn't store more than 1KB or so in a keychain entry, and you should also avoid having a lot of keychain entries.

If you need to encrypt a large amount of data, you should generate a random AES-256 key and store the key in keychain, then encrypt your large data using AES. Look up RNCryptor on keychain for a good library to implement this properly and ask any specific encryption questions at security.stackexchange.com.

I also wouldn't store large amounts of data in NSUserDefaults. It also is not intended to be used that way. Data should be stored in a file in one of the relevant directories defined under `NSSearchPathDirectory`, or else in iCloud.

It's a matter of performance. All of the code for working with both keychain and user defaults is based on the assumption only a small amount of data will be there. It's very fast for small amounts of data, but larger amounts will wast memory and cpu cycles/battery power. And in the case of keychain, you are also wasting the user's LTE bandwidth, since every change will be sent over the internet to every device they own.

I don't think Apple's app review team actively enforces this stuff, but it would technically violate the rules to use the API for anything other than it's intended purpose.

Comment: +1. To share our experience with the keychain, we started seeing progressively worse read/write performance the more we used it. We couldn't put our finger on what exactly was causing this issue (it wasn't the data size). We ended up creating an encrypted store in a different user defaults plist file, and stored the encryption key in the key chain for security.

Comment: Ultimately, keychain is mostly intended to store user passwords and encryption keys up to around 2048 bits. A 12 character password is 96 bytes and a 2048 bit key is 256 bytes. You really shouldn't store anything bigger than that in keychain.

Comment: I wonder why that is. They serialize data to an encrypted sqlite store. I wonder where the bottleneck is in the whole process.

Comment: thanks about that. The idea is to use it to store very small data. Your answer was amazing. Thanks.

Comment: @LeoNatan it probably has something to do with the way they handle keychain encryption, which is pretty complicated especially in iOS 7 where you can recover from a forgotten password. It has to do multiple rounds of encryption on all the data, and some of them with potentially weak encryption keys requiring a lot of CPU power spent on key derivation functions.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @RubberDuck basically keychain is encrypted multiple times, because it needs to be decrypted in many different situations with different needs/security levels. That might explain part of why it's so slow.